# Remove xmlns soap attribute from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I am trying to Copying soap message to custom xml(removing soap namespace from Envelope, Header,Body and removing namespace prefix from ResponseHeader element, everything fine expect one xmlns:soap namespace coming in ResponseHeader and  ResponseData elements.

Input:

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
<soap:Header>
<ns0:ResponseHeader>
<ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
<ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
<ns:Server>
<ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
</ns0:ResponseHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<ns2:ResponseData>
<ns2:Employee />
<ns2:MessageList>
<ns2:Message>
<ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
<ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
<ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
<ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
</ns2:Message>
</ns2:Employee>
</ns2:ResponseData>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Envelope   
xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
<Header>
<ResponseHeader>
<ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
<ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
<ns:Server>
<ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
</ResponseHeader>
</Header>
<Body>
<ns2:ResponseData>
<ns2:Employee />
<ns2:MessageList>
<ns2:Message>
<ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
<ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
<ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
<ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
</ns2:Message>
</ns2:Employee>
</ns2:ResponseData>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

My Xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="soap ns3 snss  ns0 ns1 ns4 #default" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

     <xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="soap:*" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(..))]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tns:ResponseData" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
 <ResponseHeader>
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(..))]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </ResponseHeader>
 </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Getting output:

```
<Envelope

xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
<Header>
<ResponseHeader xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
<ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
<ns:Server>
<ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
</ResponseHeader>
</Header>
<Body>
<ns2:ResponseData xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<ns2:Employee />
<ns2:MessageList>
<ns2:Message>
<ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
<ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
<ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
<ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
</ns2:Message>
</ns2:Employee>
</ns2:ResponseData>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

Please help how to get rid if xmlns:soap attribute?

Comment: Please post a **well-formed** input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This solution works in all versions of XSLT: 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0** (and is also much shorter):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:x="http:test/201/4">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='soap')]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="soap:* | x:ResponseHeader" priority="2">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='soap')]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the XML document** (well-formed):

```
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <ns0:ResponseHeader>
         <ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
         <ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
         <ns:Server/>
         <ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
      </ns0:ResponseHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:ResponseData>
         <ns2:Employee>
            <ns2:MessageList>
               <ns2:Message>
                  <ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
                  <ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
                  <ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
                  <ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
               </ns2:Message>
            </ns2:MessageList>
         </ns2:Employee>
      </ns2:ResponseData>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Envelope xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2" xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3" 
          xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4" xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5" 
          xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6" xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7" 
          xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8" xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <ResponseHeader>
            <ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
            <ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
            <ns:Server/>
            <ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
        </ResponseHeader>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <ns2:ResponseData>
            <ns2:Employee>
                <ns2:MessageList>
                    <ns2:Message>
                        <ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
                        <ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
                        <ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
                        <ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
                    </ns2:Message>
                </ns2:MessageList>
            </ns2:Employee>
        </ns2:ResponseData>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: `*[local-name()='ResponseHeader']` = bad practice. Namespaces should be used, not ignored.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, This is generally a sensible feedback. I am not sure that `ResponseHeader` will always be in that namespace, though -- this is why I literally implemented the requirement that the resulting element should be in no namespace. In other words, this expression does have its own use-cases and I believe the current problem presents such a use-case. Regardless of the fact that I believe reflecting your feedback will decrease the generality of the solution, I did just that. Any other comments?

Answer (score 0):

Neither your input nor your output is a well-formed XML. And your "XSLT" is not even an XSLT document!

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
exclude-result-prefixes="soap">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="soap:* | ns0:ResponseHeader">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/soap:Envelope">
    <Envelope> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying this to the following well-formed XML input:

```
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4"
xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <ns0:ResponseHeader>
         <ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
         <ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
         <ns:Server/>
         <ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
      </ns0:ResponseHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:ResponseData>
         <ns2:Employee>
            <ns2:MessageList>
               <ns2:Message>
                  <ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
                  <ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
                  <ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
                  <ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
               </ns2:Message>
            </ns2:MessageList>
         </ns2:Employee>
      </ns2:ResponseData>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:ns0="http:test/201/4" xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:m0="http:test/201/3"
          xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
          xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5"
          xmlns:ns1="http:test/201/6"
          xmlns:ns3="http:test/201/7"
          xmlns:ns6="http:test/201/8"
          xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9">
   <Header>
      <ResponseHeader>
         <ns:Env>Dev</ns:Env>
         <ns:Version>1</ns:Version>
         <ns:Server/>
         <ns:Name>NAME</ns:Name>
      </ResponseHeader>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <ns2:ResponseData>
         <ns2:Employee>
            <ns2:MessageList>
               <ns2:Message>
                  <ns4:Type>new</ns4:Type>
                  <ns4:Code>1</ns4:Code>
                  <ns4:Source>contract</ns4:Source>
                  <ns4:Description>new hire</ns4:Description>
               </ns2:Message>
            </ns2:MessageList>
         </ns2:Employee>
      </ns2:ResponseData>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

---

Note that the last template matching `/soap:Envelope` is included for purely cosmetic reasons. If you remove it, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
   <Header>
      <ResponseHeader>
         <ns:Env xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2">Dev</ns:Env>
         <ns:Version xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2">1</ns:Version>
         <ns:Server xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2"/>
         <ns:Name xmlns:ns="http:test/201/2">NAME</ns:Name>
      </ResponseHeader>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <ns2:ResponseData xmlns:ns2="http:test/201/5">
         <ns2:Employee>
            <ns2:MessageList>
               <ns2:Message>
                  <ns4:Type xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9">new</ns4:Type>
                  <ns4:Code xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9">1</ns4:Code>
                  <ns4:Source xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9">contract</ns4:Source>
                  <ns4:Description xmlns:ns4="http:test/201/9">new hire</ns4:Description>
               </ns2:Message>
            </ns2:MessageList>
         </ns2:Employee>
      </ns2:ResponseData>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

which is semantically identical to the previous result.

Comment: Thanks both.It will really help. I made small change to input. Expecting same output:

Comment: My initial question answered. I made small change to input and waiting for answer.

Comment: @Mike I don't see any change. In any case, if it's a small change, you should be able to make the adjustment yourself. Otherwise post a new question.

Comment: How about now Michael?

Comment: In the same way, If i have default namespace attribute ex : xmlns:"http://example.com" in Input. How to copy everything except this?

Comment: One more thing. If input message elements has attributes, Attributes are missing in output. Please help.